# Google Sheets Indexing and Matching issue

Tags: google-sheets

[CleanedData tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yjIA.jpg)  [RawData tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03oFS.jpg) I am tracking clients in google sheets with 2 different tabs, RawData and CleanedData.

Both tabs have 11 different columns, one being a "purchase date" column

The RawData tab keeps track of all clients that have signed up for info sessions regardless if they made a purchase or not, so every time a client has made a purchase it populates another row with the date of purchase.

In the cleaneddata tab I want to clean all the data from the RawData tab into one row for each client, for example if client "X" has 5 rows of data in the RawData tab but only one of those rows has his purchase date, I then want to pull that row with the purchase date into the cleaneddata tab.

The issue I'm having is that the purchase date is not copying over to the cleaneddata tab and I believe it is because it's accounting for the duplicate data rows that are in the RawData tab, that I need to be there.

The equation I'm using in the purchase date cell of the cleaneddata tab is:
=index(RawData!$A$1:$L, match(1,($A428=RawData!$A$1:$A)*($L428=RawData!$L$1:$L),0),match(J$1,RawData!$A$1:$L$1,0))

Is there anyway to rework this equation to account for the duplicates in the RawData tab so that the purchase data will copy over?

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thank you

Edit: I can not share the sheet file for security purposes but I uploaded a picture of what the RawData and CleanedData tabs look like, I need some equation or method to pull the purchase date from the RawData tab to the cleaneddata tab that also accounts for the repeated rows in the RawData tab

Comment: It is difficult to try to find a solution when we can't see the spreadsheet, sheets (and names), data ranges, data types, layout, etc. The most efficient and effective way to receive help will be if you can share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it, or to a spreadsheet that contains at least enough of a realistic representative sample to illustrate the problem and the result you want to see).

Comment: My apologies, I just edited the post with 2 example pictures for better clarification

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to get a subset of rows that match a specific criteria (such as given column in the row containing a value) you can use the `=FILTER` or `=QUERY` functions.

eg.

`=FILTER(RawData!A:L, RawData!J:J <> "")`

or

`=QUERY(RawData!A:L, "SELECT * WHERE J IS NOT NULL")`

Translated into plain English, both of these effectively say, "Get every row in the range `RawData!A:L` where column `RawData!J:J` isn't empty.

`FILTER` is fast and powerful.

`QUERY` gives you even more control but is more complex to use. You can run some operations on specific columns or change the data format. eg. If you'd like to change the format of the dates in column J from US-format to ISO-format, you could use:

`=QUERY(RawData!A:L, "SELECT * WHERE J IS NOT NULL FORMAT J 'YYYY-MM-DD'")`

See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage for the `QUERY` docs.